# What happens if rm is stopped half way through prompts?

Tags: fedora, rm

What happens if there are prompts during an `rm -R` command asking if the user would like to overwrite, and then some of the prompts are accepted, but halfway through the user aborts the command.

Are as many files as it went through until that point deleted?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/recovery.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wouldn't be any overwrite issues with `rm` but whatever the scenario, if you abort during the process, it will blindly stop where it was when it got interrupted.

There is unfortunately no way of knowing where it stopped unless you previously made a listing of what should be removed.